# How to force Python to reinstall utilities package when python can't figure out the version to install - versions: none

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install the utilities package for python 3.10, but when I run `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall utilities`, I just get an error as shown below.  What is wrong here?  How can I get this package installed?

```
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ python3 QA/lib/framework/cpap/launcher.py ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brad/Development/integration-testing/integration-testing/QA/lib/framework/cpap/launcher.py", line 22, in <module>
    from utilities import get_logger, logging
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ pip3 install utilities
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utilities
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall utilities
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utilities
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ pip3 list | grep utilities
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ pip3 --version
pip 21.3.1 from /home/brad/Development/integration-testing/venv_3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.0
(venv_3.10) brad:integration-testing$ pip3 install --ignore-installed utilities
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utilities
```

Comment: If something in your question demonstrates that there _was_ a copy of `utilities` installed in your virtualenv, I don't see it. How can you expect it to uninstall (or reinstall) something that isn't installed in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong but I just recompiled python and created a new virtual environment.  Everything works now.  When in doubt, nuke it and try again.